# unable to get deployment statu

Tags: vmware-vsphere, vmware-vcenter

During VMware vCenter 7 deployment on the second stage of installation, after a reboot, when trying to log in https://:5480/ redirects to https://:5480/configurev2/#/

**"unable to get deployment status"**

at the same time, the center itself allows entering normally through 443

This is already the 10th attempt to install. Checked all the articles about FQDN,  /etc/resolve and hostname issues. The hostname both A and PTR registered and everything resolves normally and there is plenty of space (over 1 TB)

I deploy the vCenter on OVH dedicated servers. In order to map a failover IP you need to register the MAC address on OVH first then manually enter newly generated MAC address to vm.

The vCenter appliance vm is created by the installer and MAC is generated automatically. After the first stage is completed, I have to manually shut down the vm and enter a new MAC address manually

Everything starts up, I complete the installation, but after the reboot I see the message
"unable to get deployment status"
when I installed 6.7 in the same way, there were no such problems
Has anyone experienced something similar?

There is no error in the logs that could lead to a clue

The only thing that comes to my mind is to deploy  pfsense  and distribute the local network

*vCenter version
7.0.3.01000*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find a solution to this one.
it's impossible to use a failover ip for vCenter applience , becase of MAC address generation.

so the only option is to use pfsanse or vrack and generate a local network

Comment: Sorry I only just saw your initial question - if I had seen it at the time I'd have simply said "Deploy it as according to the documentation, anything else is likely to fail"